# django template comparing data from file executing wrong code path

Tags: python, django

I have a file /tmp/something.txt the contents of the file have the following is just simply a 1

In my view I have the following

```python
class StrippedView(AccessRequired, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'stripped'
    title = 'stripped' 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        with open('/tmp/something.txt','r') as file:
            data = file.read()

        context = super(stripped, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = self.title
        context['something'] = data

        return context
```

And here is what I have in my template

```html
<tr>
            <th>
                Activate
            </th>
            {% if something == '1' %}
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{% url 'system:stripped' %}"><b>{% bootstrap_icon 'lock' %} Deactivate</b></a>
            </td>
            {% else %}
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{% url 'system:stripped' %}"><b>{% bootstrap_icon 'lock' %} Activate</b></a>
            </td>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
```

**So here is what I expect to happen**

When the file has a 1 in it then the first button displays that says activate and if the file has anything else then it will display the Activate button

**What did happen**

Instead what is happening is it is always display the Activate button

**What have I tried**

At first I wanted to know what was actually being returned so I replaced the text of the activate button with the variable like so

```python
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{% url 'system:https' %}"><b>{% bootstrap_icon 'lock' %} {{ something }}</b></a>
```

This shows me that the variable has the right data which is 1

I have also tried switching between

```html
{% if something == '1' %}
```

```html
{% if something == 1 %}
```

Both seem to have the same result and I am at a loss

Comment: `file.read()` will return a string, so  `{% if something == 1 %}`, will always fail, you should use `{% if something == '1' %}`.

Comment: I listed at the bottom that I have tried both but considering your comment I have changed the code to ```{% if something == 1 %}``` but it still does not work as expected @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Are you sure `data == '1'`, and not `'1 '`, or `'1\n'`, or something like that - with an invisible character?

Comment: Doing a quick vim on the file from the command line it doesnt have any lines or whitespace..not sure how I would verify that it doesnt from a code standpoint though @ForceBru

Comment: @user4820734, you could `print(repr(context['something']))`, for example. Or print a debug message _from Python_ if `context['something'] == '1'`.

Comment: @ForceBru you were exactly right I changed to this statement and now its working as expected ```context['something'] = data.replace(' ','').replace('\t','').replace('\n','')```

Comment: @user4820734, or just `context['https_enabled'] = data.strip()`, or even `context['https_enabled'] = int(data)`